# Show entire value range with matplotlib colorbar

Tags: python, matplotlib

So I'm trying to show the entire range of values plotted on the colorbar (in this case a `np.linspace` of 0-1).

I set the normalization so the color for values above 0.5 is always that given for 0.5 (i.e. flat top). What I want is a colorbar extending from 0 to 1 and showing the colors for this range. So you should be able to see the flat colorspace after value=0.5.

However, I can't find a way to do this. The default behaviour is to cut off the colorbar range at clim. The `extend` keyword doesn't seem to be physical/related to the data array and all `set_clim` does is change the color limits within the established limits.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import cm
from matplotlib import colorbar
from matplotlib.colors import Normalize
import numpy as np

def plotcb(vals, plims, cax):
    vmin, vmax = np.percentile(vals, plims)

    cmap = cm.get_cmap('plasma')
    cmap.set_bad('w', 1.)
    cmap_scalar = cm.ScalarMappable(norm=Normalize(vmin, vmax), cmap=cmap)

    cmap_scalar.set_array(np.ma.array(vals, mask=np.isnan(vals)))

    cb = colorbar.Colorbar(cax, cmap_scalar)
    return cmap_scalar.to_rgba(vals)



f, cax = plt.subplots()
all_values = np.linspace(0,1,100)

print plotcb(all_values, [0, 50], cax)

plt.show()
```

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: I'm a bit confused by this question, if the range is 0 to 1, where does 50 come in? Maybe the solution involves defining a non-linear colormap as in this http://www.derivativesinvesting.net/article/8227106617/nonlinear-colormap-in-matplotlib/.

Comment: My mistake, it should be 0.5 not 50 (the 50 in the percentiles is correct however). I'm changing it now and I'll just have a look at that link as well...

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you want, any value above 0.5 should have the same colour... The following code will do this, sorry not quite the same as your example and plasma colormap missing for me but hopefully idea should be helpful,

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import cm
from matplotlib import colorbar
from matplotlib.colors import Normalize
import numpy as np


class nlcmap(LinearSegmentedColormap):
    """A nonlinear colormap"""

    name = 'nlcmap'

    def __init__(self, cmap, levels):
        self.cmap = cmap
        self.N = cmap.N
        self.monochrome = self.cmap.monochrome
        self.levels = np.asarray(levels, dtype='float64')
        self._x = self.levels / self.levels.max()
        self._y = np.linspace(0.0, 1.0, len(self.levels))

    def __call__(self, xi, alpha=1.0, **kw):
        yi = np.interp(xi, self._x, self._y)
        return self.cmap(yi, alpha)


def plotcb(vals, levels, cax):

    #cmap = cm.get_cmap('plasma')
    cmap = cm.get_cmap('RdBu')
    cmap_nl = nlcmap(cmap, levels)
    cmap_scalar = cm.ScalarMappable(cmap=cmap_nl)
    cmap_scalar.set_array(np.ma.array(vals, mask=np.isnan(vals)))
    cb = colorbar.Colorbar(cax, cmap_scalar)

    return cmap_scalar.to_rgba(vals)


f, cax = plt.subplots()
all_values = np.linspace(0,1,100)
#Set levels so top 50 are all the same
levels = all_values.copy()
levels[50:] = levels[-1] 
print plotcb(all_values, levels, cax)

plt.show()
```